# Asp NET Core 2.2 on IIS in windows server problem

Tags: iis, installation, asp.net-core-2.2

we are thinking in upgrading our new projects to start using ASP .NET Core 2.2 but our windows server is constantly running and hosting a lot of applications that are running and being used.

My fear is that if I install .NET Core 2.2 hosting bundle it will reset my IIS and all applications will go offline. How can I install the 2.2 module without affecting all the other applications?

Comment: Yes, the installer does have impact on other applications. Please schedule a downtime and then install that.